# jQuery .post() function not working

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to send some data to PHP file but jQuery don't even run my PHP file. Just for the sake of testing I echo some text but I couldn't see any output. This is my code:

**jquery :**

```
.
.
.

$("#addFolder").click(function(){
    $(".folders").append("<p class='folder'>This is first folder<input type='checkbox' name='checkFolder'></p>");
    $data = {'id':document.getElementById('id').value, 'text':document.getElementById('text').value};
    $.post('addFolder.php', $data);
});
```

**addFolder.php :**

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';
include 'functions.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];

$userID = mysql_query("select id from users where username = '$user'")
$iduser = mysql_result($userID, 0)

mysql_query("insert into users_folders values ('$iduser', '$id') where id = '$iduser'") or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was a typo in a variable name.

Comment: When you have JavaScript that isn't doing what you expect a good first step is to open your browser's JavaScript console and check for error messages.

Comment: this typo is only in here, everything is ok in real code, and still it's not working.

Comment: I tried using javascript console but I get no errors

Comment: Does the $_post even get executed? Type console.log('here'); right below $("#addFolder").click(function(){        Do you see it getting logged?

Comment: _"this typo is only in here"_ - So please click "edit" and fix the typo so that we can focus on whatever the real problem is.

Comment: Did you include the above JS in a document ready handler or in a script element that appears after the `#addFolder` element? (If not the click handler won't have been bound to your element so no code will be executed when the element gets clicked.)

Comment: As you can see, I have .append() command in .js file, and it is working, so there is something else wrong. I also have similar jquery function above this code, it's for logging in, and it is working.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.post('addFolder.php', data);
```

should be

```
$.post('addFolder.php', $data);
```

There is a typo when you are passing parameters `data`

Problem in your **`addFolder.php`** following line :

```
mysql_query("insert into users_folders values ('$iduser', '$id') 
             where id = '$iduser'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I made that typo when I wrote code in this forum, everything is ok in my real code

Comment: @Alen Where is your `addFolder` id ? You clicked in this id then call `$.post`

Comment: it's in footer.php, it's only a div

Comment: @Alen `$("#addFolder").click(function(){
      console.log("Called");
      return false; 
});`. Check it is working or not.

Comment: Yes, it is working. You noticed, I also have .append command in .js file, it is also working. I think addFolder.php is not being executed at all. When I run it manually then it works

Comment: @Alen Your `addFolder.php` and your current page is in the same folder.

Comment: Yes, I keep all my files in same folder

Comment: I just started firebug, and it gives me this error: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/addFolder.php

Comment: @Alen Check my updated answer.I marked where is the actual problem.

Comment: So what should I do to fix it?

Comment: @Alen `mysql_query("insert into users_folders values ('$iduser', '$id')) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: This is the same query I made. And it's not problem here at all, I commented every line of code in addFolder.php and I still get same error in firebug which I reported

Comment: @Alen have any `.htaccess` file in your folder.

Comment: No, I don't have that file

Comment: @Alen At localhost your project folder name?

Comment: It's in default localhost folder where I run all my websites, there is nothing wrong with it, I just ran another website with no problems

Comment: ok, I finally found where was the problem. It was in this line of code: $userID = mysql_query("select id from users where username = '$user'"); I don't know what was wrong with it I just deleted it and wrote again, it worked. Thank you all and especially you @som. Now someone should delete all those comments :)

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
$.post('addFolder.php', data);
//data replace $data like =>  $.post('addFolder.php', $data);
```

so now

```
$("#addFolder").click(function(){
     $(".folders").append("<p class='folder'>This is first folder<input type='checkbox' name='checkFolder'></p>");
     $data = {'id':document.getElementById('id').value, 'text':document.getElementById('text').value};
     $.post('addFolder.php', $data);
});
```